# g++ build error when creating a Class object - "undefined reference to constructor/destructor"

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, constructor

EDIT: I created a "clone" of this project and it worked.

Used qmake to compile just like on this one, copied all my files to the new project's directory, then "add[ed] existing files" in Qt Creator. Built and no errors. (Oh, brother!)

---

I'm trying to create new class objects (add add them to a vector). However, on each line I create a class object, I get the errors

`undefined reference to 'Token::Token(...)'`

and

`undefined reference to 'Token::~Token()'`

...which seem to be referring to the constructor and destructor.

A screenshot of my IDE (Qt Creator) & the "trouble file":
[image]

I'm not sure if the problem lies within either of the following areas, but I am admittedly ignorant when it comes to header guards and have been fiddling with and am feeling shaky with my `include`'s.

**token.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H
class Token
{
public:
    Token(std::string type, std::string value, int line_num);
    ~Token();

    std::string type;
    std::string value;
    int line_num;

    std::string toString();
    std::string getType();
    std::string getValue();
};
#endif
```

**token.cpp**:

```
#include "token.h"

Token::Token(std::string type, std::string value, int line_num)
{
    this->type;
    this->value;
    this->line_num;
}
Token::~Token(){}

std::string Token::toString(){
    std::stringstream toString_stream;
    toString_stream << "(" << type << ",\"" << value << "\"," << line_num << ")";
    std::string complete_string = toString_stream.str();
    return complete_string;
}

std::string Token::getType(){
    return type;
}

std::string Token::getValue(){
    return value;
}
```

**scanner.h**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include "token.h"

enum keyword{
    Schemes,
    Facts,
    Rules,
    Queries
};

#ifndef SCANNER_H
#define SCANNER_H

class Scanner
{
public:
    Scanner();
    ~Scanner();

    std::vector<Token> token_vector;
    int current_line = 1;
    char cur_char;
    int total_tokens;
    std::string dummy;
    // keyword table (to recognize keywords)

    void scan_ident(std::ifstream &in); //(scan keyword)
    void scan_string(std::ifstream &in); //call when see a single quote
    void scan(std::ifstream &in); //for figuring out what token I have then calling appropriate function
    void skip_ws(std::ifstream &in); // skip whitespace
    keyword hashit(std::string const& in_string);
};
#endif
```

**scanner.cpp**:

```
#include "scanner.h"
#include "token.h"

Scanner::Scanner(){}
Scanner::~Scanner(){}

void Scanner::scan(std::ifstream &in){
    while (cur_char = in.get()){
        skip_ws(in);
        switch(cur_char){
        case ',':
        {
            Token new_token = Token("COMMA","\",\"",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case '.':
        {
            Token new_token = Token("PERIOD","\".\"",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case '?':
        {
            Token new_token = Token("Q_MARK","\"?\"",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case '(':
        {
            Token new_token = Token("LEFT_PAREN","\"(\"",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case ')':
        {
            Token new_token = Token("RIGHT_PAREN", "\")\"",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case ':':
        {
            char next_char = in.get();
            if (next_char == '-'){
                Token new_token = Token("COLON_DASH","\":-\"",current_line);
                token_vector.push_back(new_token);
                total_tokens++;
            }
            else{
            in.putback(next_char);
            Token new_token = Token("COLON", "\":\"",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            }
            break;
        }
        case '\n':
            current_line++;
            break;
        case '\'':
            Scanner::scan_string(in);
            break;
        default:
            if (isalnum(cur_char)){
                scan_ident(in);
            }
            else{
                Token new_token = Token("ERROR","",current_line);
                token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            }
            break;
        }
        if (token_vector.back().getType() == "ERROR"){
            break;
        }
    }
    if (token_vector.back().getType() != "ERROR"){
    Token new_token = Token("EOF","\"\"",current_line);
    token_vector.push_back(new_token);
    total_tokens++;
    }
}

void Scanner::skip_ws(std::ifstream &in){
    while (isspace(cur_char)){
        cur_char = in.get();
    }
    if (cur_char == '#'){
        std::getline(std::cin, dummy);
        if (!in.eof()){
            current_line++;
        }
    }
}

void Scanner::scan_string(std::ifstream &in){
    std::string curString = "\'";
    while (cur_char != '\''){
        if (cur_char == '\n' || in.eof()){
            Token new_token = Token("ERROR","",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
        }
        else{
            curString += cur_char;
            cur_char = in.get();
        }
    }
    if (cur_char == '\''){
        curString += cur_char;
        Token new_token = Token("STRING","\"" + curString + "\"",current_line);
        total_tokens++;
    }
}

void Scanner::scan_ident(std::ifstream &in){
    std::string curString = "";
    while (isalnum(cur_char)){
        curString += cur_char;
        cur_char = in.get();
    }
    if (isdigit(curString.at(0))){
        Token new_token = Token("ERROR","",current_line);
        token_vector.push_back(new_token);
    }
    else{
        switch(hashit(curString)){
        case Schemes:
        {
            Token new_token = Token("SCHEMES","Schemes",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case Facts:
        {
            Token new_token = Token("FACTS","Facts",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case Rules:
        {
            Token new_token = Token("RULES","Rules",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        case Queries:
        {
            Token new_token = Token("QUERIES","Queries",current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            Token new_token = Token("ID",curString,current_line);
            token_vector.push_back(new_token);
            total_tokens++;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}

keyword Scanner::hashit(std::string const& in_string){
    if (in_string == "Schemes") return Schemes;
    if (in_string == "Facts") return Facts;
    if (in_string == "Rules") return Rules;
    if (in_string == "Queries") return Queries;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "scanner.h"

int main()
{
    Scanner myScanner;

    std::ifstream in ("in10.txt", std::ifstream::in);

    myScanner.scan(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the `token.cpp` source file included in the project? I mean, not only existing in the same folder on the disk, but actually in the QtCreator project?

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of *text*. Instead copy the actual text into the question body.

Comment: I'm more of a visual guy--I thought the colors & layout would help people visualize it better :[ And yes, All the associated files are both in the actual system folder and in the project's list of files

Comment: Well if we see the actual text, in full, complete and unedited, it's easier to see what the error messages actually *say* (including informational notes), instead of seeing just part of them.

Comment: Would you mind to put the compilation lines ? And also, remove the #include "token.h" in scanner.cpp as you already put it in scanner.h

Comment: `qmake Project.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug` seems to be what Qt Creator does & thanks for the tip!

Comment: ^ Hopefully I didn't give the impression that the issue was solved (It's not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems at your code. First of all lines like

```
#ifndef SCANNER_H
#define SCANNER_H
```

should be at the very begining of the file, before all includes etc.

Second, why do you do this extra coping?

```
Token new_token = Token("Q_MARK","\"?\"",current_line);
```

This line should be like

```
Token new_token("Q_MARK","\"?\"",current_line);
```

Third, methods

```
std::string getType();
std::string getValue();
```

should be declared with `const`:

```
std::string getType() const;
std::string getValue() const;
```

Comment: Thanks for these tips. Clears some things up for me :) Accepted as answer due to fact that there really was no clear answer...(Just had to make a new project and move over the files)